# What is a tight prior?

Tags: bayesian, prior

In a [paper that I was reading](http://faculty.missouri.edu/~nix/papers/July03.pdf) Bayesian stats, they are talking about a "tight" prior.

> We control the “tightness” of the Minnesota prior by adjusting the
>   values of parameter $b1$. A tight version of the Minnesota prior is de
>   ned by $b1 = 0.2^2$, and a loose version sets $b1 = 0.9^2$.

Is a tight prior the same thing as an "informative prior"?

Is it saying that the variance of a distribution, if we take the example of a normal distribution, is smaller?

Comment: They say directly in the article: "We control the “tightness” of
the Minnesota prior by adjusting the values of parameter b1. A tight version of the Minnesota prior is defined by b1 = 0.2^2, and a loose version sets b1 = 0.9^2. Here the words “tight” or “loose” are used in relative terms. One can certainly argue that b1 = 0.9^2 represents a tight prior compared to the case b1 = 10^2." You can *say* one is more "informative" than the other, but it's equally loose and informal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A tight prior is indeed a concentrated prior, so a `Normal(0, 1)` prior for a parameter is more tight than a `Normal(0, 10)` prior. This is a relative statement, it depends on the scale of your parameter.

A tight prior is also more informative I would say, although informative has a connotation of being helpful, while a tight prior has less of an opinion, it's just tight.

But sure, if you have a more informed prior opinion of the variable, you would express that with a tighter prior.